# Optimizing ruby code for parsing a string to a numeric value

Tags: ruby, testing, optimization, speed-test

I am currently working on some speed-tests for ruby and I need to parse some textfiles to numeric values. Due to the slow speed I was wondering if my code could be optimized, or if ruby really is that slow.
The code is being read from files, these files contain something around 1 000 000 randomly generated lines or numbers, I will only display a few lines, so that you know what is being read.
The filenames I need to read are being passed as arguments, the coed are separate scripts (just for my own clarity).

First I want to parse a simple number, the input comes in this format:

```
type
number

type
number

...
```

This is how I did it:

```
incr = 1

File.open(ARGV[0], "r").each_line do |line|
  incr += 1
  if incr % 3 == 0
    line.to_i
  end

end
```

Second I need to parse to a single list, the input comes in this format:

```
type
(1,2,3,...)

type
(1,2,3,...)

...
```

This is how I did it

```
incr = 1

File.open(ARGV[0], "r").each_line do |line|
  incr += 1
  if incr % 3 == 0
    line.gsub("(","").gsub(")","").split(",").map{ |s| s.to_i}
  end

end
```

Finally I need to parse to a list of lists, the input comes in this format:

```
type
((1,2,3,...),(1,2,3,...),(...))

type
((1,2,3,...),(1,2,3,...),(...))

...
```

This is how I did it:

```
incr = 1

File.open(ARGV[0], "r").each_line do |line|
  incr += 1
  if incr % 3 == 0
    line.split("),(").map{ |s| s.gsub("(","").gsub(")","").split(",").map{ |s| s.to_i}}

  end

end
```

I do not need to display any results, I am just speedtesting, so there is no need for an output. I did check the outcome and the codes themselves seem to work correctly, they are just suprisingly slow and I would like to speedtest with the optimum of what ruby has to offer.
I know that there are several speedtests out there I could use, but for my purpose I need to build my own.

What can I do better? How can this code be optimized? Where did I go wrong, or is this already the best ruby can do?
Thank you in advance for your tips and ideas.

Comment: What is "type" in each file? Is it always "type"? Is it a data-type specifier for the following line?

Comment: type is meant for another program I am testing with, it is specific, but ruby never reads it, thus you can just ignore its there. I put it there so you know why the iteration works as it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first one, instead of:

```
File.open(ARGV[0], "r").each_line do |line|
```

Use:

```
File.foreach(ARGV[0]) do |line|
```

And instead of:

```
  incr += 1
  if incr % 3 == 0
```

Use:

```
 if $. % 3 == 0
```

`$.` is a magic variable for the line number of the last read line.

In the second one, instead of:

```
line.gsub("(","").gsub(")","").split(",").map{ |s| s.to_i}
```

Use:

```
line.tr('()', '').split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

In the third one, instead of:

```
line.split("),(").map{ |s| s.gsub("(","").gsub(")","").split(",").map{ |s| s.to_i}}
```

Use:

```
line.scan(/(?:\d+,?)+/).map{ |s| s.split(',', 0).map(&:to_i) }
```

Here's how that line works:

```
line.scan(/(?:\d+,?)+/)
=> ["1,2,3,", "1,2,3,"]

line.scan(/(?:\d+,?)+/).map{ |s| s.split(',',0) }
=> [["1", "2", "3"], ["1", "2", "3"]]

line.scan(/(?:\d+,?)+/).map{ |s| s.split(',', 0).map(&:to_i) }
=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I didn't run any benchmarks to compare speed, but the changes should be faster too because the `gsub` calls are gone. The changes I made weren't necessarily the fastest ways to do things, they're more-optimized versions of your own code.

Trying to compare the speed of Ruby to other languages requires knowledge of the fastest ways of accomplishing each step, based on multiple benchmarks of that step. It also implies you're running on identical hardware and OS and your languages are all compiled to their most efficient-for-speed forms. Languages make tradeoffs of memory use vs. speed, so, while one might be slower than another, it also might be more memory efficient.

Plus, when coding in an production environment, the time to produce code that works correctly has to be factored into the "which is faster" equation. C is extremely fast, but takes longer to write programs than Ruby for most problems, because C doesn't hold your hand like Ruby does. Which is faster when the C code takes a week to write and debug, vs. the Ruby code that took an hour? Just stuff to think about.

---

I didn't read through @tadman's answer and the comments until I finished. Using:

```
map(&:to_i)
```

used to be slower than:

```
map{ |s| s.to_i }
```

The speed difference depends on the version of Ruby you're running. Originally using the `&:` was implemented in some monkey-patches but now it's built-into Ruby. When they made that change it sped up a lot:

```
require 'benchmark'

foo = [*('1'..'1000')] * 1000
puts foo.size

N = 10
puts "N=#{N}"

puts RUBY_VERSION
puts

Benchmark.bm(6) do |x|
  x.report('&:to_i') { N.times { foo.map(&:to_i) }}
  x.report('to_i') { N.times { foo.map{ |s| s.to_i } }}
end
```

Which outputs:

```
1000000
N=10
2.0.0

             user     system      total        real
&:to_i   1.240000   0.000000   1.240000 (  1.250948)
to_i     1.400000   0.000000   1.400000 (  1.410763)
```

That's going through 10,000,000 elements, which only resulted in a .2/sec difference. It's not much of a difference between the two ways of doing the same thing. If you're going to be processing a lot more data then it matters. For most applications it's a moot point because other things will be the bottlenecks/slow-downs, so write the code whichever way works for you, with that speed difference in mind.

---

To show the difference the Ruby version makes, here's the same benchmark results using Ruby 1.8.7:

```
1000000
N=10
1.8.7

            user     system      total        real
&:to_i  4.940000   0.000000   4.940000 (  4.945604)
to_i    2.390000   0.000000   2.390000 (  2.396693)
```

---

As far as `gsub` vs. `tr`:

```
require 'benchmark'

foo = '()' * 500000
puts foo.size

N = 10
puts "N=#{N}"

puts RUBY_VERSION
puts

Benchmark.bm(6) do |x|
  x.report('tr') { N.times { foo.tr('()', '') }}
  x.report('gsub') { N.times { foo.gsub(/[()]/, '') }}
end
```

With these results:

```
1000000
N=10
1.8.7

            user     system      total        real
tr      0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.011652)
gsub    3.010000   0.000000   3.010000 (  3.014059)
```

and:

```
1000000
N=10
2.0.0

             user     system      total        real
tr       0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.017230)
gsub     1.900000   0.000000   1.900000 (  1.904083)
```

---

Here's the sort of difference we can see from changing the regex pattern, which forces changes in the processing needed to get the desired result:

```
require 'benchmark'

line = '((1,2,3),(1,2,3))'

pattern1 = /\([\d,]+\)/
pattern2 = /\(([\d,]+)\)/
pattern3 = /\((?:\d+,?)+\)/
pattern4 = /\d(?:[\d,])+/

line.scan(pattern1) # => ["(1,2,3)", "(1,2,3)"]
line.scan(pattern2) # => [["1,2,3"], ["1,2,3"]]
line.scan(pattern3) # => ["(1,2,3)", "(1,2,3)"]
line.scan(pattern4) # => ["1,2,3", "1,2,3"]

line.scan(pattern1).map{ |s| s[1..-1].split(',').map(&:to_i) } # => [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
line.scan(pattern2).map{ |s| s[0].split(',').map(&:to_i) }     # => [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
line.scan(pattern3).map{ |s| s[1..-1].split(',').map(&:to_i) } # => [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
line.scan(pattern4).map{ |s| s.split(',').map(&:to_i) }        # => [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

N = 1000000
Benchmark.bm(8) do |x|
  x.report('pattern1') { N.times { line.scan(pattern1).map{ |s| s[1..-1].split(',').map(&:to_i) } }}
  x.report('pattern2') { N.times { line.scan(pattern2).map{ |s| s[0].split(',').map(&:to_i) }     }}
  x.report('pattern3') { N.times { line.scan(pattern3).map{ |s| s[1..-1].split(',').map(&:to_i) } }}
  x.report('pattern4') { N.times { line.scan(pattern4).map{ |s| s.split(',').map(&:to_i) }        }}
end
```

On Ruby 2.0-p427:

```
               user     system      total        real
pattern1   5.610000   0.010000   5.620000 (  5.606556)
pattern2   5.460000   0.000000   5.460000 (  5.467228)
pattern3   5.730000   0.000000   5.730000 (  5.731310)
pattern4   5.080000   0.010000   5.090000 (  5.085965)
```

Comment: chaing the way the files are read makes no significant difference, but `tr` and `split` seems the way to go whereas `scan` appears to be a lot slower.

Comment: `scan` is replacing a bunch of `gsub` and `split` calls, so it has to be compared to the entire chain of those. It can't be tested on its own. Also, the regex pattern used affects the speed of `scan`. I can think of many different ways to extract the information, but used the first that came to mind when I wrote my `scan` example; It wasn't necessarily the fastest. A correctly written pattern can be extremely fast, equal to other means of extracting data, or vastly outrunning them.

Comment: I did not test it on its own, I tested the whole code and it was slower.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear where your performance problems are, but as far as implementation goes, there's a few things that are decidedly un-optimal.

If you're searching and replacing to remove particular characters, avoid running `gsub` repeatedly. It will take considerable time to process and re-process the same string for each character. Instead do it in one pass:

```
s.gsub(/[\(\)]/, '')
```

The `[...]` notation inside a regular expression means "set of the following characters", so in this case it's either open or close bracket.

An even more efficient method is the [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) method that is intended for remapping or removing single characters and is usually much faster as no regular expression is compiled or executed:

```
s.tr('()', '')
```

Another trick is if you're seeing the pattern where you have a block that consists of a method call with no arguments:

```
map { |x| x.to_i }
```

This collapses down into the short-form:

```
map(&:to_i)
```

I'm not sure if that benchmarks faster, but I wouldn't be surprised if it did. That's an internally generated proc.

If you're concerned about absolute speed, you can always the performance-sensitive part as a [C or C++ extension to Ruby](http://guides.rubygems.org/c-extensions/). Another option is using [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) with some Java to do the heavy lifting if that's a better fit, though usually C comes out on top for low-level work like this.

Comment: I think neither gsub nor tr should be used in this case, and scan should be used (with nesting for the third case).

Comment: using the &:to_i idiom is actually slower than map {|s| s.to_i } idiom, both in jruby-1.6.7.2 and ruby 1.8.7 (the only two I have locally to test with)

Comment: @HolgerS I think what @mcfinnigan is suggesting is that you can use `scan` to scrape out the numbers and process them that way rather than the `split` plus `gsub` combination you have now. For example: `scan(/\d+/)` pulls out all strings of digits.

Comment: @mcfinnigan Ruby 1.9.3p429 shows the `map(&:to_i)` method is slightly faster (~5%) when benchmarked against 10,000,000 numbers. There were a number of improvements between 1.8.7 where the `&:proc` shorthand method `Symbol#to_proc` where in 1.8.7 it's a feature of ActiveSupport and 1.9 where it's fully native.

Comment: @tadman That's good to know - I'll be interested to see whether the performance gain carries over in jruby-1.7 since the &:symbol is something we use frequently in our codebase

Comment: @tadman: this seems worse, the second solution using `tr` gave me the best results.

Comment: @mcfinnigan, see the benchmark I added to my answer. Ruby's use of `map(&:...)` is much faster than it used to be.